# Adjust div-element to page background

Tags: css, html

i want to create a webpage with a background image and a container I want to stick at a fixed position. If I work with absolute values and position arguments like `margin-left` I'm able to set all of the positions.

Imagine you have a colored picture as background and you want to place your header-elment at a certain point, because it contains the grayscaled area of the picture.

This works well if I neither change the screen resolution nor the size of the browser window.

**Update** 
an example can be found in the following jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fqpLu7xj/ .The header element should be placed at the certain point so both backgrounds are matching. If the page is resized the minimal size is the one of the header element.

How can I make this page responsive in this case?

Comment: Please prepare some jsFiddle or another example and provide some code.

Comment: you need to post some code so we can start investigating what you did

Comment: i've added a jsFiddle with a simple example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the full background image,this should to the trick:

```
html { 
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Now lets add a div:

Html:

```
<div id="container"></div>
```

Css:

```
#container{
 width: 80%;
 height 15%;
 border: 1px solid #fff;
 position: fixed;
 top: 1%;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
}
```

Further you can style it as much as you want.

Comment: that correct, but i want to put container at a fixed point of the background. your approach will put at a relative value. also if the window shrinks i should hide parts of the background itself.

Comment: @jwacalex , if i understand correctly , a fixed position to the container will do it , also check my answer,i've updated it.

Comment: yes it should do it, but what happens when I resize the page? will be  the container still at the same place

Comment: thanks for your example. i've convinced the designer that pixel-positioned layouts are not good for web things, but your solution worked for me.